# Python Selenium - Chrome Driver Version 75 Error

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have Chrome v75. The following code returns an error.

```
selenium.webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path='NUL', executable_path=info['location'] + '/Variables/Common/Browsers/chromedriver.exe', options=ops, desired_capabilities={'binary_location': 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'})
```

and the error,

```
*** selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
```

How can I install 2 versions of Chrome? (on 1 Windows profile)

I tried a portable Chrome version but chromedriver will not accept the Chrome.exe.

Pls help! Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you're able to have a singular profile with 2 versions of chrome, if I understood correctly. However, you could adjust your profile whenever you see fit, to make use of multiple versions as long as you're also able to adjust the correct path of both the Chrome Driver and the Chrome Binary.

Below is an example of using a singular profile, as well as an example of a multi profile whereby we loop through our key, value pair within our dictionary and consume those adjustments within our method.

**Singular profile**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def single_profile():

    """ Initiate Chrome Options """
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    """ Set Driver and Binary Path """
    options.binary_location = r'C:/chromium-version-XX/chrome.exe'
    driver_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver-version-XX.exe'

    """ Create Chrome instance with our parameters """
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=driver_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    single_profile()
```

**Multi-Profile**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def multi_profile(binary, chromedriver):

    """ Initiate Chrome Options """
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    """ Set Driver and Binary Path """
    options.binary_location = binary
    driver_path = chromedriver

    """ Create Chrome instance with our parameters """
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=driver_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':


    profiles =  {
      "chromedriver-version-1" : "chromebinary-version-1",
      "chromedriver-version-2": "chromebinary-version-2"
    }

    """ loop through our dict into our method          """
    """ Note: use profiles.iteritems(): for python 2.X """
    for chromedriver, binary in profiles.items():
        multi_profile(binary, chromedriver)
```